# Networking Transmission Details

Tags: networking, transmission, protocol

Is there some way in Ubuntu(commands or tools) to find Network Connection data packet's detail at Physical layer or Upper layers(Data, Network, Transport) up-to bit level. I want to analysis the whole procedure with Protocol details. Any help related to this is very much welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wireshark,tcpdump,ntop are the tools which can help you to do packet analysis.

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark

sudo apt-get install tcpdump

sudo apt-get install ntop
```

use those commands to install.

Documentations are best resources to learn:

Wireshark : https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html/

ntop: http://www.ntop.org/support/documentation/

tcpdump : http://www.tcpdump.org/#documentation

Hope it helps you.